# Find and list all found files within a folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to find and list all found files within a folder, and all found files within a folder that are a .txt file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will search all files and output only the files with .txt into a text document called print.txt. This will only work in the current directory, you can always string a cd to change the directory to what you want to search.

```
dir /b *.txt > print.txt
```

Say your batch file is in a USB (E drive) but you want to search C drive (not sub directories), the entire batch would look like this. @Echo OFF stops the commands from showing in the prompt, cd will change the directory to what you want to search in, "E:\print.txt" will choose the location to print the text file. I have encapusled the location in quotations in the event your destination drive has a folder with a space in it.

Have a look at some [DIR COMMAND SWITCHES](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) to print more details about the files.

```
@Echo OFF
cd C:
dir /b *.txt > "E:\print.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your help! So its not possible to change where the print.txt is created?

Comment: It is, I will edit my answer for you to change location.

Comment: Thanks i'll update my code for that. My fix for now was to create the file, then move it to where I wanted to using the "move" command.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dir *.txt` on the directory you want to search text files for.

Comment: Thank you for responding... I really appreciate it!